# Issue with media created of a video file and extracting the timestamp of each frame in it

Tags: python, opencv, datetime, win32com

I have two things to ask or confirm.

My aim is to acquire the exact date and timestamp of each frame in a video based on the media created and display it in the output video using **cv2.putText()**.

To do this, my plan was to get the UNIX-formatted timestamp of the video file's media created and the position of each frame in millisecond, divide it by 1000 to convert to seconds, then add it to the media created UNIX-formatted timestamp.

Basically for each frame, this is the plan:
**UNIX-formatted media created value + cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)/1000 = date and timestamp of the nth frame**

This is the corresponding code:

```
from win32com.propsys import propsys, pscon # excluded from the for loop, only imported once

# Get media created UNIX-formatted timestamp of the input video
properties = propsys.SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(videofilepath.replace('/', '\\'))
dt_property = properties.GetValue(pscon.PKEY_Media_DateEncoded).GetValue()
input_video_creation_timestamp_unix = dt_property.timestamp()

# Calculate the date and timestamp of the frame then display it using cv2.putText(). Please do note that this is applied to each frame of the input video
im0 = cv2.putText(im0, f'{datetime.fromtimestamp(input_video_creation_timestamp_unix + (vid_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)/1000))}', (50,150), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 1, (0, 255, 0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA)
```

However, I am having issues with the value of media created and getting the timestamp of a frame in a video.

1.) I am sourcing my input videos from Tapo TC70 from TP Link. The media created shown in Properties>Details has discrepancies with the value of **dt_property**. For instance, refer to this image [image]

As you can see, the displayed date and timestamp from the home security camera was delayed by approximately two (2) seconds. Is this normal, do you know what causes why does this happen, and the possible fixes I can do?

2.) The second problem is shown in this image [image] There is discrepancy of approximately once second when calculating the final date and timestamp for a 2-minute video. Do you know how I can also approach this problem to have the exact date and timestamp displayed as the one displayed by Tapo TC70?

I'll provide more details regarding my question if you need them or if there is something missing.

I hope for your responses. Thank you.

Comment: wrong library. use ffmpeg/PyAV. -- creation time isn't really a thing on linux systems. on windows, it "changes" if the file is a copy. -- what makes you think the surveillance camera will *create* the file at the exact instant of the first frame? -- your question isn't even about opencv, it's about win32 file system properties or the precise behavior or that surveillance camera, right?

Comment: Hi, Christoph. Thank you for your response. I am using the "Media Created" from Properties>Details and not the "Created" from Properties>General. I also don't know why the surveillance camera why or if it will (or will not) create the file at the exact instant of the first frame. About the question, I guess you're right, it is also mainly about win32 file system properties. May I ask for some details on how I can use ffmpeg/PyAV to address my problem? Thank you.

Comment: opencv is for computer vision. it has *very simple* means to read video files. the frame timestamps may not be correct. use the library that opencv uses: ffmpeg.